# How to construct a binary tree from a infix string with brackets?

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, stack, binary-tree

A non-empty tree is defined as {L,a,R}, L is left subtree, and R is Right subtree. {} for subtree is empty.
for example, {{{{},3,{}},2,{{},1,{}}},4,{{{},5,{}},6,{}}} constructs an binary tree like the picture.[tree constructed from the string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwHg3.png)

I have found a question for constructs an binary tree from a prefix expression with brackets, but I still have no idea for how to doing this.

Comment: In essence you already have a binary tree right there, it just is not a very practical implementation... as it is a string. But you'll have to tell us which is the target structure you want this binary tree to be represented in. Is it class based, object oriented? What is the programming language?

Comment: Iterate through the string one character at a time. When you encounter a closing `}`, immediately return the tree you have built. When you encounter a `{`, make a recursive call to build a subtree starting here. When you encounter a comma `,`, add the current element to the tree and begin building a new element. When you encounter another character, add it to the current element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get a reply on which data structure or language you expect to use, but here is an implementation of a recursive parser in JavaScript.

It uses a regular expression to tokenise the input into braces and data.

From those tokens it creates instances of a typical `Node` class.

Finally it outputs that structured tree in a simple, rotated view:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(left, value, right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.value = value;
        this.right = right;
    }
    
    toString() {
        return (this.right ? this.right.toString().replace(/^/gm, "  ") + "\n" : "")
             + this.value
             + (this.left ? "\n" + this.left.toString().replace(/^/gm, "  ") : "");
    }
}

function createTree(s) {
    const tokens = s.matchAll(/,([^{},]+),|[{}]|(.)/g);

    function getToken(expect) {
        let [all, value, error] = tokens.next().value;
        value ||= all;
        if (error || expect && !expect.includes(all)) throw "Unexpected '" + all + "'";
        return value;
    }

    function dfs(readOpening) {
        if (readOpening) getToken("{");
        if (getToken("{}") == "}") return null;
        const node = new Node(dfs(), getToken(), dfs(true));
        getToken("}");
        return node;
    }
    
    return dfs(true);
}

// Demo
const s = "{{{{},3,{}},2,{{},1,{}}},4,{{{},5,{}},6,{}}}";
const root = createTree(s);
console.log(root.toString()); // rotated view, with root at the left
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. And sorry for not discribing the question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answerign my question. I finally came up with an naive method by myself. I used recursive function to deal with token and create nodes. It used a counter to judge whether brackets is closed. Here is my code in C++.

```
createTree(string inp){
    int leftBracket = 0,rightBracket = 0;
    if (inp.length() <= 2) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 1;;i++) {
            if (leftBracket == rightBracket && inp[i] >= '0' && inp[i] <= '9') {
                treeNode* newNode = new treeNode(inp[i]-'0', createTree(inp.substr(1, i - 2)), createTree(inp.substr(i + 2, inp.length() - i - 3)));
                nodeCounter++;
                return newNode;
            }
            else {
                if (inp[i] == '{') {
                    leftBracket++;
                }
                else if (inp[i] == '}') {
                    rightBracket++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```